# file upload not working on internet explorer 8 and 9

Tags: ajax, file, upload, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

```
function uploadFile(){

   var file = $("file1").files[0];
   var formdata = new FormData(); formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php";
    ajax.send(formdata);

}
```

Error1: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Error2: ForData not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FormData` API is not supported by IE8 or IE9. It was only added in IE10. If you want to support these old browsers, then you cannot use modern HTML5 APIs.

There is a jQuery Forms plugin which does work in old IE versions and can allow you to upload files via ajax. I've used it myself and it is very effective. You can download it here: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/. You will probably need to rewrite your code a fair bit in order to use it as it's quite different conceptually to the HTML5 FormData API, but at least you'll get something that will work across all the browsers you want to support.

You could also try looking to see if there's a polyfill for FormData which would allow you to keep using your existing code. A quick google turned up [this one](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie), which I found listed [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). I haven't tried it so can't vouch for it, but the polyfills listed by Modernizr on that list are generally pretty good.